# Construct a line segment of length $x/\sqrt{2}$ using straightedge and compass

Tags: geometry

I am trying to figure out how to draw line segments of length ${x \over \sqrt{2}}$. In General draw line segments of length involving radical & variable in it.

Comment: Half a diagonal of a square of side $x$

Comment: That should be a basic construction.  What have you tried? or what thoughts have crossed your mind as to how to proceed?

Comment: @N74, don't you mean $x/2$ for the side?

Comment: @danpost it's the same

Comment: @N74 Sorry -- overlooked the 'Half' part.

Comment: a square of side x the 1/2 diagonal comes out to xroot2/2

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Create two perpendicular lines of length x/2 then join their ends and then erase the perpendicular lines you will get a line of length root(x)

Comment: D'oh.  That's pretty darned.... obvious.  +1

Comment: Thanks @fleablood

Answer (score 3):

You only need a square and a so-called V-figure to get the right ratios:

[image]